# Mapping two MEDIA_URLs to the same MEDIA_ROOT

Tags: django, media, wagtail

I’m migrating a website from WordPress to Django/Wagtail. I have all the old WP content in my `media` directory & it’s all being served appropriately.

It would be convenient to map other URLs (specifically `/wp-content/`) to `MEDIA_ROOT`, for the sake of old media URLs that were hardcoded in the content.

So for example a migrated asset now available at `//example.com/media/uploads/2017/12/IMG_2120.jpg` can also be served from `//example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/IMG_2120.jpg`

I’m sure there’s some obvious way to do this (in `urls.py`?) but totally drawing a blank.

Comment: What webserver are you using (Apache, Nginx...)? This would be best handled through your web server's configuration, rather than through Django - usually you'd want to avoid serving static files through Django.

Comment: Yep. See Xyres’ answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you already know that static/media files should be served using a frontend server (like Nginx), because it's been mentioned at so many places in the docs.

So, if Django doesn't serve the files, why does it need the `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` settings?

`MEDIA_ROOT` is the place where Django stores the images/files you upload.

`MEDIA_URL` is used by Django to generate file urls. For example, if `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`, then if you do `{{ image.url }}`, Django will generate a url like this - `/media/image.jpg`.

But Django doesn't serve the files. Your frontend server does. So, what you do is, you configure your frontend server like this:

```
if request path starts with /media/:
    map it to <media directory>
```

Basically, you're telling your frontend server to serve content from the `<media directory>` for every request that starts with `/media/`. This way, a request starting with `/media/` never actually reaches your Django app, because your server is taking care of them.

What I mean by all this is that you can configure your frontend server to map `/wp-content/uploads/` to your `<media directory>` and it will serve the files.

Comment: Yup this was the obvious answer I was missing.