# Handling media django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to handle the django static and media content. This is my code in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

In urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I am uploading files and videos to my site, everything is working fine even static and media content is being displayed.

**My actual doubt is-**

I am actually running in development environment. In production for collecting the static content generally `python manage.py collectstatic` is used and then it is handled. But in development according to docs, app called `django.contrib.staticfiles` is used serve static files. But what about media files, how are they served actually ??

When I upload a image it is getting stored to `project_name/media/app_name` insted of `project_name/app_name/media/app_name` as static files are being accessed from path similar to latter, why are media files being stored in different manner.

Finally:

1. How the media files got served in development ?
2. How to serve media files in production ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I upload a image it is getting stored to `project_name/media/app_name` insted of `project_name/app_name/media/app_name` as static files are being accessed from path similar to latter, why are media files being stored in different manner.

Media files are uploaded to the `MEDIA_ROOT` directory. Your `MEDIA_ROOT` is `media`, so django will keep uploaded files there.

Additionally, if in the `FileField` or `ImageField` you use `upload_to` path, django will create required folders accordingly. For example, for something like this:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='myapp/')
```

Django will create a `myapp` folder inside `media` and keep the uploaded images there.

> 1. How the media files got served in development ?

Because of this line of code:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

It tells django to serve `MEDIA_ROOT` directory at `MEDIA_URL`.

> 2. How to serve media files in production ?

Configure your webserver to serve media and static files. Django doesn't serve media and static files because it's not good at that. An actual webserver like Nginx or Apache is configured for serving static files efficiently.

Comment: really thankyou for the reply but `Media files are uploaded to the MEDIA_ROOT directory. Your MEDIA_ROOT is media, so django will keep uploaded files there.` ` even my `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` but I am actually accessing my static files from `project_name/app_name/static/app_name` instead of `project_name/static/app_name` why ?

Comment: @SandeshGhanta For static files, django looks inside `app_name/static/*` folders, as well as the folders listed in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. Here's the relevant documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders

Comment: @SandeshGhanta Basically, what happens is that you tell Django (or a webserver) to serve a particular folder at a particular URL. You can serve multiple folders at a single URL. So, if a request comes in at `/media/my-file.jpg`, Django will find `my-file.jpg` inside the folder mentioned in `MEDIA_ROOT`. Then serve the file. I wrote a detailed answer about this sometime ago - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48013313/1925257. The same is happening with `STATIC_URL`. Django is serving multiple directories under a single `/static/` URL.

Comment: @SandeshGhanta But when you run `collectstatic`, Django will collect all your static files -- from inside your app folders, or from the main static folder -- and put it inside the directory mentioned in `STATIC_ROOT` settings. Then you'll configure your actual web server to serve the contents of `STATIC_ROOT` at `/static/` url.